# Resolving order of execution among multiple HandlerMapping(s)

Tags: spring-mvc

If an application consists of multiple handler mappings then **in which order they will be given preference to execute ?**.

Different handler mappings could be -

1. BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping
2. SimpleUrlHandlerMapping
3. ControllerPathMapHandlerMapping
4. CommonPathMapHandlerMapping

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set the order of a handlermapper with the Ordered interface. from the doc:

> Note: Implementations can implement the Ordered interface to be able
>   to specify a sorting order and thus a priority for getting applied by
>   DispatcherServlet. Non-Ordered instances get treated as lowest
>   priority.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html